# CkEditor toolbar config inside Vue component

Tags: ckeditor

Does anyone have any idea, what the names are in this array, to configure the toolbar of CkEditor. Like in the docs, you can simply and easily configure the tool bar like this:

```
    editorConfig: {
      toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic', '|', 'paste' ]
    },
```

The only issue is, that those names in the array are WELL hidden. I've been looking for an hour and not able to find anything for the `editorConfig` in the `data` elements of my component. There are TONS of examples to be placed in the mysterious `config.js` file, but no clue where that goes. So I'm sticking with this.

Anyone anywhere have any idea what these names are?

Answer (score 0):

This example will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60135719/4322960

```
            editor: ClassicEditor,
            editorData: 'ckeditor 5 for laravel and vuejs',
            editorConfig: {
                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'heading',
                        '|',
                        'bold',
                        'italic',
                        '|',
                        'bulletedList',
                        'numberedList',
                        '|',
                        'insertTable',
                        '|',
                        'imageUpload',
                        '|',
                        'undo',
                        'redo'
                    ]
                },
                image: {
                    toolbar: [
                        'imageStyle:full',
                        'imageStyle:side',
                        '|',
                        'imageTextAlternative'
                    ]
                },
                table: {
                    contentToolbar: [ 'tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells' ]
                },
            },
```